# Classes to be assigned pictures?

Tags: c#, class, user-interface, picturebox

So right now I have a GUI program that I was working on last night and it's almost done, though some graphical changes will be made. But I was wondering if it were possible to display a picture based on a class. 
Like,

```
Employee John = New Employee("John", "Doe")
```

How would I make it so a picture displays with John Doe's face? Do I use a picture box or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of ways to do this, of course, but you might decide to store some reference to the image you want to use.  Maybe you'd do that in your Employee class by holding the path to it like so:

```
public class Employee
{
   public string Picture { get; set; }
   // ..
}
```

Then you could just load that up, assuming it's a path

```
pictureBox1.Load(employee.Picture);
```

Another approach would be to hold the actual image in the Employee object itself like so:

```
public class Employee
{
   public Image Picture { get; set; }
   // ..
}
```

and load those up ahead of time.  Depends on how many you've got in your collection of employees.

Assuming they're already loaded as `Image` objects in the employees, you're just calling

```
pictureBox1.Image = employee.Picture;
```

Comment: What do you mean by that?  Do you want to show multiples on the screen at the same time?

Comment: Well I wanted to pick a random employee and then show their information, one at a time.

Comment: OK, so the selection works however you select them, right?  Assuming you've picked the employee from the collection, now you just need to populate the UI with the properties from that employee object and set the picturebox content.